# Calling Python functions from inline C with scipy.weave

Tags: python, performance, inline, scipy

Can I call a python function from inline C code (using weave)?

Motivation:
I have a bit of code that I'd like to optimize, and I've identified the bottleneck in one function. After my usual tricks, I usually turn to [scipy.weave.inline](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.weave.inline.html) for optimization. Unfortunately, in this case, my function is calling another python function in an inner loop. I've made sure that the inner function isn't causing the speed issue, and I really don't want to have to write it in C as well.

Minimal Example:

```
from weave import inline

def foo(x):
    return x*2

def bar():
    a = 0
    for i in xrange(10):
        a += foo(i)
    return a

def bar_weave():
    code = """
    int a = 0;
    for (int i=0;i<10;++i){
        a += foo(i);  //<<-- what I'd like to do, but doesn't work
    }
    return_val = a;"""
    return inline(code,['foo'])

print bar()
print bar_weave()
```

Comment: Is that your actual foo function?

Comment: No, that's just an example of the structure. My actual foo function is complex enough that writing it in C as well would be quite painful, especially because it's not my bottleneck.

Comment: What is foo called on, and how many times is it called?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's a little involved, as Weave doesn't have a way to automatically marshall the arguments and return value.  You need to do a little more work:

```
def bar_weave():
    code = """
    int a = 0;
    for (int i=0;i<10;++i){
        py::tuple arg(1);
        arg[0] = i;
        a += (int) foo.call(arg);
    }
    return_val = a;
    """
    return inline(code,['foo'])
```

Output:

```
90
```